# How can I rewrite this map() example using list comprehension?

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, lambda, list-comprehension, nested-lists

```
orders = [ ["34587",("5464", 4, 9.99), ("8274",18,12.99), ("9744", 9, 44.95)], 
           ["34588",("5464", 9, 9.99), ("9744", 9, 44.95)],
           ["34588",("5464", 9, 9.99)],
           ["34587",("8732", 7, 11.99), ("7733",11,18.99), ("9710", 5, 39.95)] ]
```

I want a new list of as a result, with the first element ("34587") and other elements from tuple multiplied (example: 4*9.99, 18*12.99, 9*44.95)

Can be achieved with `map()`:

`list(map(lambda x: [x[0]] + list(map(lambda y: y[1]*y[2], x[1:])), orders))`

Result:

`[['34587', 39.96, 233.82, 404.55], ['34588', 89.91, 404.55], ['34588', 89.91], ['34587', 83.93, 208.89, 199.75]]`

Question is, can this map() example be rewritten as list comprehension?

Thanks.

Comment: `list(map(lambda x: expression_involving_x, l))` is equivalent to `[expression_involving_x for x in l]`. With that knowledge, you should be able to perform the conversion on your own. Focus on converting one `map` call at a time.

Comment: What troubles me is that I have two lambda functions in this example, and I don't know how to express them in listcomp. Tried  `[(x[0], y[1]*y[2]) for x in orders for y in orders[0]]` and `[(x[0], y[1]*y[2]) for x in orders for y in orders]` but getting `TypeError` errors for trying to multiplicate different types.

Comment: Two `map` calls translate to two list comprehensions, not one with two `for` clauses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As in one comment, map with lambda:

```
list(map(lambda y: expression_involving_y, elements))
```

can be exchanged with list comprehensions:

```
[expression_involving_y for y in elements]
```

You can start with substituting your inner map:

```
list(map(lambda x: [x[0]] + list(map(lambda y: y[1]*y[2], x[1:])), orders))
```

having `elements` as `x[1:]` and `expression_involving_y` as `y[1]*y[2]` to:

```
list(map(lambda x: [x[0]] + [ y[1]*y[2] for y in x[1:] ], orders))
```

And you can repeat the substitution to finally get to your result:

```
[ [x[0]] + [ y[1]*y[2] for y in x[1:] ] for x in orders ]
```

Comment: Code-only answers are candidates to be deleted by moderators. Just say you are using a nested comprehension and explain a little bit about that comprehensions can be nested, then your answer would be a good one.